# NgRx: how do I declare the explicit type of an action created by action creator?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, ngrx

After starting a new application and using NgRx's new action creator pattern, I have found myself missing having an explicit type for an action. For example when I'm testing a service, I would like to know that it dispatched the correct action with the correct properties.

How do I go about this while retaining type safety in TypeScript?

An example:

```js
// What should the '???' in the following line be?
spyOn(store, "dispatch").and.callFake((action: ???) => {
  expect(action.type).toBe(fetchProductStructureAction.type);
  // TypeScript complains here if I don't add the correct type to action
  expect(action.property).toBe(expectedProperty); // <--
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put there `Action` from `ngrx/store`.

this one works for sure.

```js
spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callFake((action: Action) => {
  expect(action).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
    type: fetchProductStructureAction.type,
    property: expectedProperty,
  }));
});
```

if you want to keep the original type in the callback then you need to cast method to `any`, but then it brings to the case with `ReturnType` for creator functions.

```js
spyOn(store, "dispatch" as any).and.callFake((action: MyActionCreatorFunction) => {
  expect(action.type).toBe(fetchProductStructureAction.type);
  expect(action.property).toBe(expectedProperty);
})
```

Comment: This will work, thanks. I think it's a pity that we lose the typing of the action, though. If I were to refactor the action to change the property name, my editor couldn't make the change in this test automatically.

To be honest, I'm failing to see why action creators are the new default. We give up so much to gain a few characters on declaration...

Comment: IMO I wouldn't allow autorename in tests to be sure someone really touched the code to ensure it won't be broken after. Anyway I got your requirement now and check today for a better solution that would allow it.

Comment: The test is an example, but I've needed this in other places of the code as well. So far, the only thing that has worked has been `ReturnType<typeof myActionCreator>` but it's really verbose and ugly, especially for newbies.

Comment: I found a way with `any`, might you check if it works for you?

Comment: You're using `FetchProductStructureAction` as a type, so this action wasn't created with an action creator function?

Comment: it's just my guess how the class of `fetchProductStructureAction.type` is called. If you use a creator function simply put there its type like `typeof fetchProductStructure`.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. My question was originally if there is a good way to notate the type of an action created with an action creator without having to use ReturnType<typeof myActionCreatorFunction> but apparently there isn't. I'll mark your answer as it does solve the specific example I mentioned.

Comment: Ah, I see, then yes, you are right, not much we can do here to simplify things.

Comment: I think as an option you can write an assert function that verify the type, something like `ngrxAction(action, myActionCreatorFunction)` and it asserts that action follows it - then code below should understand all properties, but it comes with TS 3.8

Answer (score 0):

As Luis Aceitune mentioned, this works:

```
ReturnType<typeof myActionCreator>
```

Example:

```
export const loadDataAction = createAction('[Example] Load Data', props<{ id: string }>());

type LoadDataAction = ReturnType<typeof loadDataAction>;
```

[image]